# AngularJS routeProvider when hash sign is present

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have an app hosted on IIS. The app url is 
`http://localhost/tool`

When I load the page by typing in this url, the url path changes to

`http://localhost/tool#/tool`

I don't have anything in the `$routeProvider` config.
I would like to process a URL request like,

`http://localhost/tool#/request/:param1/:param2` or if possible
`http://localhost/tool#/request?param1=Value&?param2=value`

How do I write the `$routeProvider` configuration?

Further in my situation, user needs a direct URL to get the state of the page so the user may not start with `http://localhost/tool` but could start with `http://localhost/tool#/request/:param1/:param2`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do think is possible to have an url like localhost/tool#/request?param1=Value&?param2=value but :

```
angular.module('myApp').
    config(
        ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/tool', {templateUrl: './view/partial/tool_list.html', controller: ToolListCtrl}).
                    when('/tool/:param1/:param2', {templateUrl: './view/partial/tool_details.html', controller: ToolDetailCtrl}).

                    otherwise({redirectTo: '/tool'}); //here you can redirect to whatYouWantUrl
        }
        ]);
```

You will find all informations you need here: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Isn't there any `stateProvider` or something ? I need to show the state of the app based on the URL. so in your second router parameter, the `templateUrl` will be the same for me except extra details will be added based on the request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

E.H. is right with the routing setup. If you want to pass the routing parameters into your controller you do that like this (from the tutorial he linked):

```
function PhoneDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
}
```

If you want to keep track of "state" as in managing other data based on what is getting passed in, you have to do that yourself. I have done this by using a service and injecting it into the controller(s) if you need to access it from multiple places.